# Simple OpenID in Java

Tags: java, authentication, openid

I'm new into OpenID. Is it possible to do something like this in Java against OpenID?

```
String username = "user";
String password = "pass";

OpenID openID = new OpenID(username, password);
```

And then I retrieve something... callback, event... something like

```
void opedIDAuthenticatedSuccessfully(OpenIDEvent event) {
    String id = event.getID;
    String user = event.username;
    ...
}
```

It would be lovely!

Answer (score 2):

There is an OpenID library for Java: http://code.google.com/p/openid4java

> This library allows you to OpenID-enable your Java webapp.
>
> The following specifications are supported:
>
> - OpenID Authentication 2.0
> - OpenID Authentication 1.1 (in compatibility mode)
> - OpenID Attribute Exchange 1.0
> - OpenID Simple Registration 1.0 and 1.1, draft 1
> - OpenID Provider Authentication Policy Extension 1.0
> - OpenID Information Cards 1.0, draft 1

Answer (score 1):

The entire idea behind OpenID is that the relying application (the one asking for authentication) never is allowed to handle the user's actual authentication credentials, which keeps the user's credentials more secure and gives the application less to worry about.

So, no, there isn't a way to do what you are looking for with OpenID because what you are asking for ex *exactly the opposite* of how OpenID works.

Answer (score 0):

OpenID Attribute Exchange is an OpenID service extension for exchanging identity information between endpoints. Messages for retrieval and storage of identity information are provided. More see in [doc](https://openid.net/specs/openid-attribute-exchange-1_0.html)

OpenID Connect 1.0 is marketed as an Authentication solution. [Difference between Authentication and Authorization](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-authentication-and-authorization/)

OpenID is about verifying a person's identity. If you don't know difference between OAUTH, OpenID and OPENID see [good explanation](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44611/difference-between-oauth-openid-and-openid-connect-in-very-simple-term/44614#44614)

Libraries for work with java see in [openid-specs](http://lists.openid.net/pipermail/openid-specs/2007-December/005041.html)